# javascript not compatible with IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

My script does not work properly with Internet Explorer. The problem is that the 'data' (JSON.stringify (data);) is not updated with the new values ​​after the script has been run once, it updates the div's with the same values as ​​the first time it was run. I am a newbie when it comes to js, have no idea how to solve this. Grateful for help!

```
function ful() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var imp = "";
            var imps = new Array();
            var set = new Array();
            var div1, div2, div3, div4, tmp, hum, tid = "";
            var temp = "";
            var humi = "";
            imp = JSON.stringify(data);
            var values = imp.split(',');
            var i = 0;
            var y = 0;
            for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
                imps[y] += values[x];
                i++;
                if (i == 4) {
                    y++;
                    i = 0
                }
            }
            for (var x = 0; x < imps.length; x++) {
                div1 = "impid" + x;
                div2 = "temp" + x;
                div3 = "hum" + x;
                div4 = "tid" + x;
                set = imps[x].split('"');
                tmp = set[9];
                hum = set[13];
                tid = set[17];
                for (var y = 0; y < tmp.length; y++) {
                    temp += tmp[y];
                    if (y == 4) break;
                }
                for (var y = 0; y < hum.length; y++) {
                    humi += hum[y];
                    if (y == 4) break;
                }
                document.getElementById(div1).textContent = "ID : " + set[5];
                document.getElementById(div2).textContent = "Temprature : " + temp + " °C";
                document.getElementById(div3).textContent = "Humidity : " + humi + " %";
                document.getElementById(div4).textContent = tid;
                temp = "";
                humi = "";
                tmp = "";
                tid = "";
                hum = "";
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(ful, 6000)
}
$(ful);
```

Comment: Please specify the IE version you're having trouble with. It can make a very big difference. Also, have you tried running your code through http://jshint.com/?

Comment: `JSON` has been introduced in IE in version 8. To utilize it, you need to declare a document type, and if I can recall correctly, page also needs `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">`.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer caches ajax requests.

A simple workaround is to simply add a timestamp to the end of your request, forcing IE to get a new one. Jquery does this automatically for you when specifying the `cache` parameter with `false`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: ...
```

For other options, check out this post:
https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/fixing-internet-explorer-amp-ajax#.UcIVBZyiVSQ